# how to load url from txt file and usng imacro

Tags: url, macros

I have imacro enterprize edition. I want to load URL from a `.txt` file and visit the pages, and then fill a form. The form is the same for all the URLs. For a single page, I can make the macro but cannot make the macro that load the next URL from a `.txt` file and do the same work.

I have searched a lot and made a code that can load an URL from `.csv` file and visit a page. But it is not working. Here it is:

```
VERSION BUILD=7401004 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !DATASOURCE input.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a variable for the loop:

```
VERSION BUILD=8940826 RECORDER=FX
SET !DATASOURCE c:\input.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
...
```